# iOS 9 - stack view alignment

Tags: swift, constraints, uistackview

I have an issue when it comes to working with the new UIStackView.

My setup:

[image]

1) I added 4 constraints to the vertical-stackview, so the stack view is stretched throw the whole screen.

2) Next i changed all imageviews to "aspect fit"

(i set view to background blue, so you can see the spaces..)

Result:

[image]

So my screen gets separated vertically into two parts and each part contains two images where you also have some whitespace.

So my question is how to remove all the whitespace and align images at top so it will be a nice 2x2 image grid.

Ps: i know i can solve this via "collectionView" but i would like to do this via "UIStackView"

Any suggestions?

Thanks and Greetings!